# Not fill polygons in WMS?

Tags: geoserver, wms, style, getmap

[image: WMS map with white background]

Is there a way to set it up because the polygon is not filled during WMS setting.

2.18 GeoServer is in use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: try reading https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/polygons.html to see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

SLD can only be used to apply colour to geometries on your data.  If you want the background of the map to have a colour (i.e where there is no data), you have to supply a `BGCOLOR` parameter as part of the GetMap request.

If you wanted a grey background colour you'd add `BGCOLOR=#808080&` to the GetMap request